# Is combination of internal fragmentation makes external fragmentation case in Operating System?

Tags: operating-system

Is combination of **internal fragmentation is one of the external fragmentation case** in Operating System?

Suppose 100Kb unused space as internal fragmentation and a new request comes with 99Kb.Then this is also the case of external fragmentation or not?

Comment: I think you'd need to rephrase that question (unless I am the only one who doesn't understand), I have no clue what this is about

Answer (score 0):

Both internal and external are different.
For example suppose you declare one structure which contain 4 variable .
struct fragment{
int a,
char a,
int a,
char a};
Considering int is 4 byte long than total memory will be 4 byte +1byte +4byte +1byte.these 3 byte from both char will be wasted and cause internal fragmentation.

External fragmentation will come if you are executing multiple small program and all program occupy some space in ram but space is divided in such a way that even there is lots of free blocks but not one  single program can accumulate new program